# Importar node-imap con next.js

Tags: nodejs, next.js, imap

Lo que quiero hacer es ver todos los correos que he recivido desde un servidor de correos que tengo, quiero conectarme usando imap a mi cuenta de correo, pero no logro importar la liberia, estoy usando nextjs para conectarme, al importarlo me sale lo siguiente

```
import Imap from 'imap';
...
setImap(new Imap({
  user: email,
  password: password,
  host: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_HOST,
  port: 993
}))
```

y al momento de usarlo me sale este error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Imap is not a constructor
```

Y cuando uso dynamic

```
const Imap = dynamic(() => import('imap'))
```

me vuelve a salir el mismo error, entonces no se si estoy importandolo de manera incorrecta

Answer (score 1):

Imap es un módulo que necesita Nodejs para funcionar, a simple vista me parece que estás tratando de acceder a Imap desde el navegador: lo que no es posible. Si quieres usar Imap debes ejecutarlo en el servidor, en otras palabras:

- Debes crear una ruta en el folder `/api` y hacer un request en el cliente para traer esa información desde el servidor.

Si no estás familiarizado con las rutas de `/api` de Next.js, [aquí está](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction) la documentación al respecto. Es super sencillo y son MUY funcionales.

Comment: Y en cuyo caso, como puedo hacer para que siempre se mantenga conectados? que usaria en ese caso?

Comment: Si lo que quieres es saber cómo ver todos los correos que has recibido periódicamente en un lapso de tiempo determinado, eso ya es otra pregunta. Y tiene varias respuestas. Pero puedes crear un `setTimeout` que haga el fetch al servidor cada `X` cantidad de tiempo. O puedes usar una librería como [SWR](https://github.com/vercel/swr) con la opción [`revalidateOnInterval`](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/revalidation#revalidate-on-interval) y el hook se encarga de fetcher esos datos por ti.